# where can i get older version of this package as new version is failing my Docker build?

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, docker, debian

My docker build is failing after there is an update to this package (https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/9/prod/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2) I want a version of this package before the update happened (24-Jun-2020 15:09 ).

after adding the URL to source.list, **apt-get update -y** is failing.

Docker File :

```
FROM python:3.6.8

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install python-pip -y

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils apt-transport-https
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update -y

RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install msodbcsql17
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install mssql-tools
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"
RUN apt-get install unixodbc-dev

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 4040
CMD ["newrelic-admin","run-program","gunicorn", "-c", "gunicorn_config.py", "main:app"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That error usually indicates a problem with the package repository on the server side (you can test from other client machines/networks to be sure). If you can report it to someone at Microsoft, it usually gets fixed pretty quickly and you can try again after that.